# Recursive function in “for loop” quitting before it should (JS)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I am having some difficulty with writing a recursive function in javascript. I want the function to take a list item `<li>` and create a flattened array of all the `<li`’s children `<li>`s. When I add the recursion so that it will find children multiple levels deep the function seems to goes as far as it can on one branch and then quit without returning back to the for loop.

Please see my code below and the following jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jsjxn3ym/1/

```
var result = [];    

function flattenList(element){
    childrenLevel = element.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? Array.prototype.slice.call(element.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children) : undefined;
    if (childrenLevel != undefined){
        result = result.concat(childrenLevel);
        for (var u = 0, l = childrenLevel.length; u < l; u++) {
            return flattenList(childrenLevel[u]);
        }
    }
    if (result.length === 0){
        return undefined;
    }
    else{
        return result;
    }
}

var startingElement = document.getElementById('startingElement');
var functionResult = flattenList(startingElement);
```

Comment: Is the expected output of your fiddle `[A, A1, A2, B, B1, B2]` or `[A, B, A1, A2, B1, B2]`?

Comment: `result` is defined where?

Comment: @Damon Either output would work for me. Order isn't important in this case.

Comment: @epascarello Oh I forgot to add that to the code in the stackoverflow question. It's at the top of the jsfiddle. I'll edit the question to add it in.

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the fact you do not use `var`. So many globals inside code that is reused.  When you call the code, all those variables wipe away others. Use `var, const, let` they are not optional.

Answer (score 0):

you should simplify your loop. Like this it works:

```
if (childrenLevel !== undefined){
 result = result.concat(childrenLevel);
 childrenLevel.forEach(child => flattenList(child))
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With your markup you can simply do like this. A lot less complexity

```
const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul li span')).map(span => span.innerHTML);
//["A", "A1", "A2", "B", "B1", "B2"]
console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsjxn3ym/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fact you use global variables. When you call the function again you write over the values in the variable, so that causes the loop to exit out since the variable on the first iteration are no longer when you call it the second time.

```
function flattenList(element){
    childrenLevel = element  <-- childrenLevel is a global variable
```

Other issues with your code is when you are returning inside of the loop. And you are replacing the array.

```
var result = [];

function flattenList(element) {
  //you need to use var
  var childrenLevel = element.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? Array.prototype.slice.call(element.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children) : undefined;
  if (childrenLevel != undefined) {
    console.log(childrenLevel)
    //no not replace the array, append to it
    result.push.apply(result, childrenLevel)
    for (var u = 0, l = childrenLevel.length; u < l; u++) {
      flattenList(childrenLevel[u]);  //do not return here
    }
  }
  if (result.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

Use `var` when you declare variables. Or if you are in ES6, use `let` and `const`. And the other issue with your code is the fact you would need to manually reset `result` every time you want to use the function.

Now not sure why you are not just selecting all of the lis from the start instead of having to loop over them all.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('#startingElement li span')
const txt = Array.from(lis).map(o => o.textContent).join(', ')
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = txt
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="startingElement">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>A</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>A1</span></li>
          <li><span>A2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>B</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>B1</span></li>
          <li><span>B2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="log">
<h2>Log:</h2>
</div>
```